# Any Bitcoins on an old computer

Tags: cryptography

I purchased an older computer at a garage sale, the seller said her son used it from about 2008 to 2012 to play games online.  It still has the original hard drive and the seller says its been in storage since her son passed and she wants to sell it and I bought it for $20.  How would I look to see if there are any bitcoins stored on the HD?

Comment: In `%APPDATA%` is there anything that sounds like the name of a wallet software?

Comment: The only thing that looks like it might be interesting is a file called key.txt, but just a couple of pages of what looks like jibberish